# How to clear values copied and pasted beyond a named range from selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to restrict entries of values only to the named range. Everything entered outside the named range should be cleared.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Intersect(Target, Range("Liczby")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, Excel allows you to fill cells also by executing the Copy/Paste command (mouse, keyboard). My code should clear everything that has been pasted outside the named range. It should only paste partial values that fit into the named range and do not show values pasted outside the named range (clear).

For example, I select a row that contains integers 1, 2, 3, 4 in adjacent cells, and try to paste them two columns to the right. As the named range is only 4 columns width, it should paste values 1 and 2 into the named range, and not show values 3 and 4 as they go beyond the named range.

Comment: Should everything outside the named range explicitly be cleared (blank) or left untouched (remain intact, if something is already there)?

Comment: @Asger it should clear everything, nothing should be outside the named range at start or during work with the worksheet

Comment: the solution provided by @Ahmed AU works great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try each cells in target (if i understood the problem correctly)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cel As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Cel In Target.Cells
        If Intersect(Cel, Range("Liczby")) Is Nothing Then
        Cel.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You made my day.